# font "Futura" not working on any PC

Tags: css, fonts

There is a font called "Futura", it works on all macs, even iPhones, but not on PCs. So on my web hosting, I have a css file called styles.css. At the top, I have :

```
@font-face {

 font-family: 'Futura';

 src: url("Futura.eot");
 /* FOR IEs */

 src: local('Futura'), url('Futura.ttf') format('truetype');
 /* for other web browsers */

}
```

and in the same place as styles.css I have futura.ttf, and futura.eot. I got them both from a website, so I don't know if those two files are broken or not.
But all fonts still shows as Times New Roman on PC.

Comment: There are a lot of things that could be causing this... can you provide a link to a page that shows this problem for you?

Answer (score 9):

1) Make sure that the font-family value degrades gracefully:

```
font-family: 'Futura', Arial, sans-serif;
```

2) If you're hosting a copy of the font, make sure that it's on your server and the URL is pointing to it correctly. That said, if you just downloaded the font and are hoping to use it on your website, there are better ways to do this. You're going to want a web-optimized one that only includes the character sets and weights that you actually need. Otherwise, you're forcing every visitor to your site to download 200k worth of font -- no bueno. A good option would be TypeKit (http://typekit.com), which does have Futura PT.

If you're not looking to pay, the Google Web Font Repository is another fantastic resource. You won't be able to find Futura, but they have plenty of other options.

Answer (score 5):

The Futura font is copyrighted, and you can legally use it as a web font only if you have made an agreement with the font vendor, directly or indirectly. See [Linotype page on Futura](http://www.linotype.com/472/futura-family.html). Contact the font vendor regarding problems in use, after double-checking that you are using the font according to the instructions.

If you find the cost excessive, consider trying to find a suitable free font that is sufficiently similar or otherwise meets your needs. There are some nice sans-serif fonts, with several typefaces, among [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts).

Comment: thanks! will these google fonts work easly on pc and mac without doing any file stuff?

Comment: @user1906956, Google Web Fonts can be used as remotely hosted by Google, and that’s what Google suggests; you would then have just `link` elements in your own code. But in reality, it is often better to host the fonts yourself, after first generating them with FontSquirrel from the files that you download from the Google site. There have been many questions in SO that relate to such issues. But you can surely *test* and compare them the way Google suggests.

Answer (score 3):

- This would probably be safer:

  ```
  font-family: Futura, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
  ```

  via http://cssfontstack.com/
- **Also**, you might be safer using a typekit so you can ensure it will show up correctly on any OS or browser. For example: https://typekit.com/fonts/futura-pt

  [Google's WebFont Loader](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader) allows you to pull from various web fonts.

  > The WebFont Loader is a JavaScript library that gives you more control
  >   over font loading than the Google Web Fonts API provides. The WebFont
  >   Loader also lets you use multiple web-font providers. It was
  >   co-developed by Google and Typekit.
- You should also make sure you are using the correct font name. You might have a variant on your PC. For example: Futura Book BT, Futura Lt, Futura Md, Futura Bk, Futura Hv, etc.

Comment: if i did succeed in getting Futura, could i been sued for using it without permission?

Comment: Plus 1 for recommending Google WebFont Loader.